# Does Browserify have any limitations?

Tags: node.js, browser, browserify

I started to use Browserify today and it is not working too well so far.
Are there some modules that cannot be Browserified?
I tried searching online for some specifics for a while now but nothing so far.

The main problem I have so far is trying to use the **getmac** module.
I wouldn't be surprised if accessing such private info from the browser was impossible, but the following link seems to show otherwise.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/getmac

The 2 main errors I got so far is the **exec** command being undefined after the

> exec = require('child_process').exec;

and the **platform** parameter of the object **process** being undefined in

> isWindows = process.platform.indexOf('win') === 0;

These 2 lines were automatically generated by Browserify. So unless I forgot an include or to install something, it seems like it is just not supported.

I would appreciate any help you might have for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browserify only provides browser shims for the node modules listed in the [compatibility section](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#compatibility) of their documentation. If any of the modules you want to use depend on something not listed there (such as `child_process`), they will not work. There are workarounds for some (such as [browserify-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-fs), which uses a virtual file system in the browser storage), but ultimately you can't bypass any of the normal restrictions a browser has. Browserify doesn't let you run node.js code in the browser, it's just a common-js module system for the browser with some built-in shims.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! My boss might not be happy about it but at least it will make things clear!